# Overload [] subscript operator for std::any

Tags: c++, c++17, std

is there any way to overload the `operator[]` for std::any?

I have a struct looking like this:

```cpp
struct Container {
public:
  template <typename T>
  void push_back(const T &t) { 
    m_container.push_back(t);
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::any> m_container;
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to access an element by index (which can be of any type).

I think of a visitor like

```cpp
struct subscript_visitor {
 std::string operator[](const size_t &idx) {

 }

 int operator[](const size_t &idx) {

 }
 
 ...
}
```

But functions with the same return type reasonably cannot be declared.

Any idea how to solve this so that something like

```cpp
Container c; 
c.push_back(0);
std::cout << c[0];
```

Will work?

Comment: To add a generic `operator[]` to return the specific `std::any` element would be rather trivial, so I guess that's not really what you want. I guess you want to do an automatic`std::any_cast` which is much more problematic, since you don't actually know the current stored type in the `any`. I would probably add a templated `get` function instead, to access the element and do a `any_cast`. Like `template<typename T> T& get(size_t index);` and use it like `std::cout << c.get<int>(0);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to store additional info, if you want to access the type later. You could do so by storing a function pointer to a specialization of a template function used for printing. You'll need to add one data member to the vector element per function you want to access though to make this work. `std::variant` may be preferrable in this scenario depending on the use case.

```
struct Container {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void push_back(T&& t) {
        m_container.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(t));
    }

    struct Element
    {
        template<class U>
        Element(U&& value)
            : m_value(std::forward<U>(value)),
            m_printFunction(&Container::Print<U>)
        {
        }

        std::any m_value;
        void (*m_printFunction)(std::ostream&, std::any const&);
    };

    Element const& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return m_container[index];
    }

private:

    template<class U>
    static void Print(std::ostream& s, std::any const& value)
    {
        s << any_cast<U>(value);
    }

    std::vector<Element> m_container;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Container::Element const& value)
{
    value.m_printFunction(s, value.m_value);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    Container c;
    c.push_back(0);
    c.push_back(std::string("Hello World"));

    std::cout
        << c[0] << '\n'
        << c[1] << '\n';
}
```